# Excel 2010 - percent on filter value

Tags: excel, crosstab

I got this kind of database :

```
NAME    QUESTION    ANSWERED
Brian   Q1          Yes
Brian   Q1          Incorrect
Brian   Q1          No
Brian   Q1          Yes
Brian   Q2          Yes
Brian   Q2          Yes
Brian   Q2          Incorrect
John    Q1          Yes
John    Q1          Yes
John    Q1          No
John    Q1          Yes
John    Q2          No
John    Q2          Yes
John    Q2          Incorrect
```

I want to do a cross table in Excel 2010 to calculate a percent of "Yes" answered for each question.

The result should be like this :

```
         QUESTION
NAME     Q1         Q2
Brian    50%        66%
John     75%        33%
```

I mean : Brian answered 4 times to question Q1. He answered 2 times "Yes", so the percentage of yes answered is 50% (2/4*100).

How can I do this in a cross table ? I put NAME on lines, QUESTION on column, and ANSWERED on values. Know if a add a filter on ANSWERED, the percentage calculate by Excel is only on filtered values, not on the total of question Q1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 4th column with the formula =IF(C2="Yes",1,0).  Then put that in the "Values" section of the PivotTable, and calculate the Average (instead of the Sum which is the default).